# Magento how to update billing/shipping order before place order for guest

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, billing, edit-order

Magento how to update billing/shipping order before place order for guest.

I know what observer event I need to use and familiar with it. What I want to know is how to get billing/shipping or and what code write to update it. I've only found information about how to update a address of already placed order.

Answer (score 0):

I did not try this code so you should refine it on your own:
you need to have an observer that has a function to update the billing and shipping address, here is what you need to do in your xml:

```
<sales_order_save_before>
    <observers>
        <custom_observer>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>Custom_Module_Model_Observer</class>
            <method>updateaddress</method>
        </custom_observer>
    </observers>
</sales_order_save_before>
```

then in your observer you need to check if the account is a guest account and then update their quote:

```
public function updateaddress(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
    $session = $observer->getEvent()->getCheckoutSession();
    $sessionCustomer = Mage::getSingleton("customer/session");
    $quote = $this->_quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->load($session->getQuoteId());
    $address = $quote->getShippingAddress();
    if (!$sessionCustomer->isLoggedIn()) {
        $address->setData($reset);
        $quote->setShippingAddress($address);
        $quote->setBillingAddress($address);
        $quote->collectTotals()->save();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add code in sales_order_place_before event

```
public function orderPlaceBefore($observer) {

    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    $billing_address = $order->getBillingAddress();
    $shippingAddress = Mage::getModel('sales/order_address')
        ->setCustomerId($billing_address->getCustomerId())
        ->setCustomerAddressId($billing_address->getCustomerAddressId())
        ->setAddressType(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address::TYPE_SHIPPING)
        ->setFirstname($billing_address->getFirstname())
        ->setMiddlename($billing_address->getMiddlename())
        ->setLastname($billing_address->getLastname())
        ->setSuffix($billing_address->getSuffix())
        ->setCompany($billing_address->getCompany())
        ->setStreet($billing_address->getStreet())
        ->setCity($billing_address->getCity())
        ->setCountry_id($billing_address->getCountryId())
        ->setRegion($billing_address->getRegion())
        ->setRegion_id($billing_address->getRegionId())
        ->setPostcode($billing_address->getPostcode())
        ->setTelephone($billing_address->getTelephone())
        ->setFax($billing_address->getFax());

    $order->setShippingAddress($shippingAddress);
    $order->save();
}
```